# Reference request: isomorphism in $K$-theory induced by inclusion of a full corner of a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra $p$ a projection such that $ApA$ is dense in $A$. Let $B=pAp$. Then it is known that the inclusion
$$i\colon B\hookrightarrow A$$
induces an isomorphism on operator $K$-theory, i.e. the functorially induced map
$$i_*\colon K_*(B)\to K_*(A)$$
is an isomorphism.

I wonder what the basic ideas are that underlie the proof. Is there a good reference for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Proposition 2.7.19 in Willett and Yu's book "Higher Index Theory" (you can find a copy of a draft of the book [here](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Erufus/higherindextheory), or from Rufus Willett's homepage).  The idea of the proof is to reduce to the separable case, and appeal to the following result of Brown:

> If $A$ is separable and $p\in M(A)$ is a full projection, then there is an isometry $v\in M(A\otimes\mathbb K)$ such that $vv^*=p\otimes 1$.

Using this, we define a map $\phi:A\otimes\mathbb K\to pAp\otimes\mathbb K$ by $\phi(a)=vav^*$.  This is a $*$-isomorphism, and its composition with the inclusion $pAp\otimes\mathbb K\hookrightarrow A\otimes\mathbb K$ yields an isomorphism on $K$-theory, so in particular the inclusion (after tensoring with $\mathbb K$) induces an isomorphism on $K$-theory.
Finally, we have a commutative diagram
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
pAp & \hookrightarrow & A \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
pAp\otimes\mathbb K & \hookrightarrow & A\otimes\mathbb K
\end{array}
\end{align*}
where the vertical arrows are "upper left corner" inclusions.  The vertical maps and  the bottom map induce isomorphisms on $K$-theory, hence so does the top map.

Comment: Do you know where I could find a proof of the result by Brown?

Comment: The original reference is Corollary 2.6 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-71/issue-2/Stable-isomorphism-of-hereditary-subalgebras-of-C-algebras/pjm/1102811431.full).

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I find the proof of Lemma 2.5 in Brown's paper a bit opaque and wish there was a more intuitive exposition of the construction...

Comment: It is certainly a technical argument.  An alternative (though essentially the same) approach can be found in Chapter 7 of Lance's book "Hilbert $C^*$-modules".